# How to disable all alerts using selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to disable all alerts using webdriver while disabling alerts should affect as true.
Thanks
Akmal Rasool

Comment: you mean to ask, how we can handle Alerts using Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you want to check for alerts and if any alert is present you want to accept those alerts.

See the below code for the same.

```
public boolean alertPresence() 
{ 
  boolean presence = false;   
  try 
  { 
       driver.switchTo().alert();
       presence = true; 
       alert.accept();

  }  
  catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
  { 
        Ex.printStackTrace;
        presence = false; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pooja, but i want that it should check for alerts through whole process until driver is working

Comment: You can create this method in your project and call it where ever you want. You have a framework? If you give more details about your project i can help you to fix your problem...  :) I have a framework where I call this method before performing any action like click or enter